# Diferencia entre “callejón” y “calleja”

Tags: definiciones, sustantivos

¿Cómo diferenciamos ***callejón*** y ***calleja***? ¿Calleja es un tipo de callejón? ¿Es más corto?

Si es posible, documenten las respuestas con imágenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etimológicamente, una calleja es más corta que un callejón. Si miramos las definiciones del diccionario, obtenemos:

- [Calleja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pizBSh): Calle **estrecha**.
- [Callejón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pvWhBR): Paso **estrecho y largo** entre paredes, casas o elevaciones del terreno.

De hecho, la etimología de *callejón* es:

> Del aumentativo de *calleja*.

Así que en su origen un callejón era una calleja grande. Sin embargo, creo que hoy día los significados han divergido un poco. A fin de cuentas, una calleja es una calle pequeña, como su etimología indica, y las calles están pensadas para el tráfico rodado y de peatones.

Una calleja hoy día es pues una calle pequeña, tal vez peatonal, por la que hay espacio para varios peatones o incluso algún vehículo, con accesos a viviendas. La longitud no es relevante. Si paseas por el centro de Córdoba (España) recorrerás muchas callejas, como puedes ver en [este artículo](https://sevilla.abc.es/andalucia/cordoba/sevi-callejas-cordoba-ultimo-reducto-211339197203-20170927093308_galeria.html). A continuación una imagen ilustrativa:

[image: Calleja de Córdoba]

Un callejón es aún más estrecho, pasarían juntas una o dos personas, y no suele tener accesos a viviendas. Si hay un sitio que me venga a la mente cuando hablo de callejones, es Venecia:

[image: Callejón de Venecia]

En todo caso, la línea entre *calleja* y *callejón* parece un poco dispersa, así que supongo que el uso de una u otra para las denominaciones de calles puede se algo subjetivo.

Comment: la diferencia es que la calleja no necesita estar rodeada de paredes, puede ser un simple camino en medio de la nada pero muy angosto,  

callejon envuelve a la palabra "Cajon" indicando que esta cerrado y compacto. asi pues el callejon es un tipo de calleja, pero hay callejas que no son callejones

Answer (score 0):

Un callejón es una calle estrecha que discurre en una población entre edificios altos.​ Es sinónimo de callejuela y calleja.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero deberías elaborarla un poco más y, sobre todo, añadir fuentes que respalden tu respuesta.